# Should I use strip_tags() before HTML Purifier?

Tags: php, sanitization, sanitize, htmlpurifier

I'm integrating Redactor (a WYSIWYG editor) on my website and it outputs HTML instead of BBCode or Markdown. I need to allow the following tags as it uses them for formatting:

```
<code><span><div><label><a><br><p><b><i><del><strike><u><img><video><audio><iframe><object><embed><param><blockquote><mark><cite><small><ul><ol><li><hr><dl><dt><dd><sup><sub><big><pre><code><figure><figcaption><strong><em><table><tr><td><th><tbody><thead><tfoot><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>
```

From what I've read and been told on here, in order to safely display the content I should store the original data in my database, along with a sanitized version (output by HTML Purifier) which is what I will actually output (the unsanitized version being there in case anything goes wrong when sanitizing it).

My question is, should I call `strip_tags()` on the data as well (passing the above tags as the allowed tags argument), or should I pass it directly to HTML Purifier?

Comment: You can set a whiltelist with html tags and attributes in for htmlpurifier. So you dont have to call `strip_tag()` first, but maybe it is faster to first call it, so htmlpurifier dont have to check that much html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that you can likely reduce the parsing work that a parser like HTML Purifier does by filtering out tags before the fact, there's no security gain in using `strip_tags()` first, and in your use-case it likely isn't going to make much of a difference.

The reason it won't make much of a difference is, of course, that your average submitted content will not be malicious, and thus be submitted via your WYSIWYG, which is only going to generate those tags that you already want to allow. As such, you wouldn't strip out any tags in the preliminary `strip_tags()` run for those comments.

Meanwhile, a malicious submission is likely to bypass any benefit `strip_tags()` would give you, anyway. However, using `strip_tags()` before the parser won't do harm, and it *could* help guard against attempts to use the parser against you by letting it eat up a lot of resources - though *if* the parser can cause issues (I'd expect it to have safeguards against that), that tends to happen through nesting depth, not through tag.

In brief:

I see no reason to recommend it in your case; but I see no reason to dissuade you from using it, either. `strip_tags()` is pretty fast and it won't mangle anything if you use it before the parser.

Comment: The only exception I could think of is invalid HTML, which will likely look different if processed by only HTML Purifier or `strip_tags` + HTML Purifier. But one probably doesn't need to care about this case much anyway.